# Trying to display the list in QListView?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

Can't get the list to display?

[image]

```
/*create QListView */
m_listViewA = new QListView(this);
m_listViewA->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0,100), QSize(100, 150)));

modelA = new QStandardItemModel( nrow, 1, this );

//fill model value
for( int r=0; r<nrow; r++ )
{
    QString sstr = "[ " + QString::number(r) + " ]";
    QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString("Idx ") + sstr);
    modelA->setItem(r, 0, item);
}
//set model
m_listViewA->setModel(modelA);
m_listViewA->setSelectionMode( QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection );
```

---

```
QStringList slist;
foreach(const QStandardItem index, modelA) //ERROR
{
    slist.append( index.data(Qt::DisplayRole ).toString());
}
```

Comment: <QStandardItemModel> is included.  Only the code at "slist" is giving problems.

Comment: Ooups sorry hadn't noticed the `*` in the first error message.

Comment: You'd need to dereference the model for the `foreach` to have a chance at it working, but I don't think you can use a model in a foreach like that. Not sure why you're not filling the slist at the same time you're building your model either.

Comment: sorry different method

Comment: `QStringListModel` may be more convenient in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works... but would rather use "foreach"...

```
QString strA;
for(int r=0; r < modelA->rowCount(); r++)
{
    strA += "\r\n" + modelA->item(r,0)->text();
}
QMessageBox *msgBox = new QMessageBox(0);
msgBox->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(200,200),QSize(400,400)));
msgBox->setInformativeText(strA);
msgBox->exec();
```

Comment: foreach would require a container with all (top-level) items, but such an accessor doesn't exist for QStandardItemModel.